Confidence interval for ${θ}/{2}$ in $\text{U}(0, \theta)$
I am trying to find a confidence interval for ${\theta}/{ 2}$ with confidence level $1-\alpha$ (using quantiles at $p_1 = \alpha$ and $p_2 = 1$).  So I take unbiased estimator for ${\hat{\theta}}/{2} = {X_{(n)}}/{2}$.  Then from what we learned in class:
$$\mathbb{P} \bigg( \dfrac{cX_{(n)}}{2\theta} \leqslant q_{p_1}  \bigg)
= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \dfrac{X_{(n)}}{\theta} \leqslant \dfrac{2q_{p_1}}{c} \bigg)
= \alpha
= \bigg( \dfrac{2q_{p_1}}{c} \bigg)^n,$$
which implies $q_{p_1}=\tfrac{c}{2}\alpha^{{1}/{n}}$ and the same process for $q_{p_2}$ will give us $q_{p_2} = {c}/{2}$.  This gives:
$$\mathbb{P} \bigg( \dfrac{c}{2}\alpha^{{1}/{n}} \leqslant \dfrac{cX_{(n)}}{\theta} \leqslant \dfrac{c}{2} \bigg)
= \mathbb{P} \bigg( X_{(n)} \leqslant \dfrac{\theta}{2} \leqslant \dfrac{X_{(n)}}{\alpha^{{1}/{n}}} \bigg)
= 1-\alpha,$$
so the resulting CI is:
$$\dfrac{\theta}{2} \in \bigg[ X_{(n)}, \dfrac{X_{(n)}}{\alpha^{{1}/{n}}} \bigg].$$
Does this look correct? Or am I missing anything?

Find a CI for $\theta$ and divide that by $2.$  This will help you see the problems with your current attempt.

$\frac \theta 2$ is the mean of your $U(0,\theta)$. And in the case of the continous uniform distribution, the CLT converges very rapidly (requires sample sizes as small as 5).

@jginestet While it's true that the standardized sample mean converges to a normal quite rapidly, the sample mean would be a very inefficient way to estimate $\theta/2$ in this instance, unless $n$ was very small - the standard error of the MLE goes to zero in proportion to $n^{-1}$ instead of $n^{-\frac12}$ (the way the mean does). Correspondingly, a CI based on the sample mean will attain the correct coverage fairly quickly as $n$ increases, but will on average be very wide compared to one based on the MLE.  It would also not be likely to accord with what the student is expected to do here

You can form an optimal (shortest) confidence interval for this case
Firstly, contrary to your post, your estimator is biased (see e.g., here).  This does not particularly matter for the formation of your confidence interval, but it is a useful thing to note.  To form your confidence interval, define the quantity:
$$R = \frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}.$$
which has distribution function:
$$F_R(r) = r^n
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\text{for } 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1,$$
and corresponding quantile function:
$$Q_R(p) = p^{1/n}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\text{for } 0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1.$$
This gives us a pivotal quantity which can be used to form a confidence interval.  To form an interval for the confidence level $1-\alpha$ we take a control parameter $0 \leqslant \phi \leqslant \alpha$ and form the probability interval:
$$\begin{align}
1-\alpha
&= \mathbb{P}(Q_R(\alpha - \phi) \leqslant R \leqslant Q_R(1-\phi)) \\[16pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(Q_R(\alpha - \phi) \leqslant X_{(n)}/\theta \leqslant Q_R(1-\phi)) \\[10pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \frac{X_{(n)}}{Q_R(1 - \phi)} \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{X_{(n)}}{Q_R(\alpha-\phi)} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \frac{X_{(n)}}{2 Q_R(1 - \phi)} \leqslant \frac{\theta}{2} \leqslant \frac{X_{(n)}}{2 Q_R(\alpha-\phi)} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \frac{X_{(n)}}{2 (1 - \phi)^{1/n}} \leqslant \frac{\theta}{2} \leqslant \frac{X_{(n)}}{2 (\alpha-\phi)^{1/n}} \bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Any value of $0 \leqslant \phi \leqslant \alpha$ will give you a valid confidence interval formed from the above probability interval.  (A common choice is to take $\phi=\alpha/2$ which gives an equal tail interval.)  Best practice is to optimise the confidence interval by choosing the appropriate control parameter to minimise its length (see e.g., O'Neill 2022).  To do this, we first observe that the scaled length of the above interval (as a function of the control parameter) is:
$$\begin{align}
S(\phi)
&= \frac{1}{(\alpha-\phi)^{1/n}} - \frac{1}{(1-\phi)^{1/n}}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
This is minimised by taking $\phi=0$ which gives the resulting (optimised) confidence interval:
$$\text{CI}_{\theta/2}(1-\alpha) = \bigg[ \frac{x_{(n)}}{2} , \frac{x_{(n)}}{2 \alpha^{1/n}} \bigg].$$
This confidence interval should perform well for estimation of $\theta/2$.  This interval estimator is consistent if the underlying sampling model is correct, meaning that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the interval length shrinks to zero for any $0 < \alpha \leqslant 1$ (while maintaining its a priori coverage probability).
